# No output from /etc/init.d/postfix start

Tags: centos, postfix

i try to run postfix version postfix-2.3.3-6 already installed on my CentOS 5.6 server , but it shows FAILED msg when i use this command

```
/etc/init.d/postfix start
```

Ok i tried to unveil the source of problem with /var/log/syslog and /var/log/messages but for the first one it says no such file in directory and for the second command another msg says that the permission is denied what should i do ? any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The permission denied message for `/var/log/messages` suggests that you're not doing it with root privileges, which in turn makes me wonder if you're not starting `postfix` as root, either.  You will most definitely need to run an MTA as root for it to work.

Try `sudo /etc/init.d/postfix start` (assuming you use sudo to get root privilege), and if that still fails, try `sudo tail /var/log/messages`.

**Edit**: OK, the error message you've found in `/var/log/maillog` is very likely the indicator of the failure-to-start problem, since it says `warning: valid_hostname: misplaced delimiter: u1y3nntoq0. fatal: unable to use my own hostname`, and fatal errors are rarely good for software.

Could you find out if there's some issue with a declaration in your postfix config files with `grep u1y3nntoq0 /etc/postfix/main.cf`, and if that doesn't find anything, with `find /etc/postfix -type f -exec grep u1y3nntoq0 {} /dev/null \;` ?  The output of `hostname` would also be most helpful.

**Please edit this output into your question, above, by using the edit link; don't keep adding comments, not least because they destroy the formatting.**

Comment: thanks for reply MadHatter, i have tried  `sudo /etc/init.d/postfix start` but it FAILED!  and second give me this message :`lookup_read_master: lookup(nisplus):                                                                              couldn't locate nis+ table auto.master`

Comment: Could we get a few more lines from `/var/log/messages` than that, say the last ten?  If there's a `/var/log/maillog` could you also give us the last ten lines from that.  You should probably edit them into your question, not just post them as a comment.  Thanks!

Comment: The NIS+ error message looks like a messed up `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (as I assume there is no NIS+ in sight). What does that file contain?

Comment: Cjay, I've no idea what you just put in there.  I asked for the tails of two files, and **please edit them into your question**, not add them as comments.

Comment: i put the rest of the msg when i tried `sudo tail /var/log/messages`

Comment: MadHatter, this command `/var/log/maillog` says `warning: valid_hostname: misplaced delimiter: u1y3nntoq0.
fatal: unable to use my own hostname`